# Why this code makes wrong minimal spanning tree by Prim's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, go, queue, priority-queue

I have some code on Golang with Prim's algorythm.
The task is to find minimal spanning tree with a minimum amount of edge lengths. But if vertices number is greater then 3, I'm getting wrong answer.

So I tried to rewrite Prim's algorythm, but nothing changed.

```golang
func MST_Prim(vertices []*Vertex, vertNum int, edgeNum int) []*Edge {
    treeEdges := make([]*Edge, 0)

    for i := 0; i < vertNum; i++ {
        vertices[i].index = -1
    }

    queue := make(PriorityQueue, 0)
    v := vertices[0]
    for i := 0; i < vertNum; i++ {
        v.index = -2

        for _, edge := range vertices[v.id].edges {
            u := vertices[edge.v]

            if u.index == -1 {
                u.priority = edge.len
                u.value = v.id
                queue.Push(u)
            } else if u.index != -2 && edge.len < u.priority {
                u.value = v.id
                queue.update(u, v.value, edge.len)
            }
        }

        if queue.Len() == 0 {
            break
        }

        v = queue.Pop().(*Vertex)
        treeEdges = append(treeEdges, &Edge{v.id, v.value, v.priority})
    }

    return treeEdges
}
```

I need to print minimal sum of length of edges in minimal spanning tree.
There is the input:

```
4
4
1 2 462
0 3 343
0 1 430
1 3 146
```

I'm getting 1038 as answer, but correct answer is 951.

Comment: Two things: 1) You add a new edge `vertNum` times. However, a tree will always have `vertNum - 1` edges. 2) You assume that a vertex is not in the queue if its index is `-1`. This is not true as another neighbor vertex might already have pushed it into the queue.

Comment: @NicoSchertler 1) Do you mean adding a new edge to queue? 2) The function uses same adresses of vertices in array `vertices` and array `queue`.

Comment: 1) No, I mean `treeEdges = append(...)`. 2) I mean the `.index`. You assign either `-1` or `-2`. Btw, you might also want to check if your data type can hold negative numbers.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yeah, you're right. But actually cycle controlled by `if queue.Len() == 0` line and I don't think that `vertNum` plays any role in this cycle. Field `index` has `int` as type, so I think it should be able to hold negative numbers.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Forgot to reply. I assign `-1` for vertices which didn't put in a queue yet or was taken earlier, and `-2` for the vertex which I took from queue in current iteration.

Comment: You do the following: `if u.index == -1 ... queue.Push(u)`. But `u` might already be in the queue.